# About tornado.access:404 announce.php

Tags: aptana, tornado

I use Aptana IDE develop tornado project. But often in console auto print:
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /announce.php?info_hash=%A2%...

How is this going?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a torrent-related request (http://www.trancetraffic.com/anatomy.php).  Are you running your app on a port that is commonly used by bittorrent?

Comment: I don't know, I just running test tornado in Aptana, Can you tell me how stop it working?